# Control R channel volume from L channel

Tags: sound, level

I have a mono line level (signal and GND) and I want to create L and R channel from it (to output sound to 2 separate speaker) BUT I want to be able to control the volume of the R channel.

Creating L and R is pretty easy, I just connected the signal line (from the mono line level) directly to L and R of my amplifier and it works fine (I connected GND too, of course.) Whenever there is sound in the mono line level, both L and R speaker play the sound perfectly.

To be able to control the R channel in order to be able to make it quieter I took a 1k potentiometer and soldered it like below:

[image]

This works fine, I mean, when I rotate the potentiometer, the R channel gets quieter and quieter according to the potentiometer position, but I realized that when I rotate the potentiometer, the L channel changes a bit too, not as much as R but it still gets its volume changed. How can I prevent this? How can I control R channel volume without affecting the L channel?

​

Comment: @winny the problem I related happens not when shorting the signal, it starts right after the resistor goes from 1k to 900 ohm... As soon as I turn the potentiometer from 1k to 900ohm the sound on R channel starts to increase and the sound on L also starts to increase!

Comment: Sorry, I misread you. See Mattman’s answer below.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to imagine what is inside your pre-amp and amp. Your amp will have some series resistance, to protect from damage. The amp will have some resistance to ground to suppress noise when the input is open. The internal circuits could be more complicated than I have shown, but this is close enough to discuss. The resistance is probably higher than I have shown, I made everything 1k for simplicity.

When the pot is in the CW position, there is an extra 1k load, so the volume on the L channel will decrease slightly.

How to avoid this? You could try a larger value pot, but that may cause other issues. You could reduce the output impedance of the pre-amp (not wise, since then it will be more susceptible to damage). You could add another amp before the pot, but that is probably way more complicated than you want.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI3bAu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>